# Integrate the following differential equation: $y' = \frac{x^2+2y^2}{xy}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to integrating the following differential equation, and would like your feedback on my solution. I seem to be going wrong somewhere in rearranging my equations.

$y' = \frac{x^2+2y^2}{xy}$

What I have done:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2+2y^2}{xy} \implies dy = \frac{x^2+2y^2}{xy}dx \implies ydy =\frac{x^2+2y^2}{x}dx$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I cannot divide by $2y^2$ because its bound by $dx$. However, when I approach it this way:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2}{xy}+\frac{2y^2}{xy} \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y}+\frac{2y}{x}$$

Then divide both sides by $\frac{1}{2y}$

$$\frac{dy}{2ydx} = \frac{x}{2y^2}+x$$

The second approach fails me towards the right answer. I would really appreciate some guidance!

Comment: maybe this helps: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24y%27%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%2B2y%5E2%7D%7Bxy%7D%24&p=1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: multiply both sides by $y$ to get

$$yy' = x + \frac{2}{x} y^2.$$

Then note that $yy' = \frac{1}{2}(y^2)'$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2}{xy}+\frac{2y^2}{xy} \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y}+\frac{2y}{x}$$

---

You can continue from this line. It's homogeneous. Substitute $y=tx \implies y'=t'x+t$:
$$t'x+t = \frac{1}t+{2t}$$
This ODE is separable.

---

You can easily integrate the ODE:
$$y' = \frac{x^2+2y^2}{xy}$$
$$t'x+t=\dfrac {1+2t^2}{t}$$
$$t'x=\dfrac {1+t^2}{t}$$
This is separable.